Upgraded to node:22-alpine from 16-alpine and `.bin` stopped appearing in `node_modules`
This is in a gitlab runner. Wiped cache. It works fine locally. Any ideas for debugging this?

Node pushed a bug in 22.5 that impacted the npm install process. Official recommendation is to downgrade to 22.4 for now.
Issue to track:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/53934?utm_content=300836743&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter&hss_channel=tw-91985735
